# SASL authentication failed; server said: 530 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

Tags: amazon-ses, postfix-mta, amazon-lightsail

I set up postfix with Lightsail and SES according to this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/postfix.html
When I send emails, the emails in the queue say this:
`SASL authentication failed; server email-smtp.ca-central-1.amazonaws.comhttp://99.79.137.249 said: 530 Must issue a STARTTLS command first`
I have tried changing different settings for `smtp_tls_security_level = dane` (current), `smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt`, `smtp_tls_security_level = may` but emails still don't go, although the status might change with a different setting.
I can provide more detailed logs if necessary.
Thanks!

logs

```
Feb 22 13:51:43 ip-172-26-12-131 postfix/smtpd[936667]: connect from unknown[45.142.120.6]
Feb 22 13:51:43 ip-172-26-12-131 postfix/smtpd[934814]: warning: unknown[45.142.120.137]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Feb 22 13:51:43 ip-172-26-12-131 postfix/smtpd[934814]: disconnect from unknown[45.142.120.137] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=3/4
Feb 22 13:51:46 ip-172-26-12-131 postfix/smtpd[924010]: warning: unknown[45.142.120.84]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Feb 22 13:51:46 ip-172-26-12-131 postfix/smtpd[924010]: disconnect from unknown[45.142.120.84] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=3/4
Feb 22 13:51:47 ip-172-26-12-131 postfix/pickup[922446]: 0A680BE63C: uid=1000 from=<mail@example.com>
Feb 22 13:51:47 ip-172-26-12-131 postfix/cleanup[939757]: 0A680BE63C: message-id=<20210222185147.0A680BE63C@ip-172-26-12-131.ec2.internal>
Feb 22 13:51:47 ip-172-26-12-131 postfix/qmgr[633056]: 0A680BE63C: from=< mail@example.com >, size=357, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Feb 22 13:51:47 ip-172-26-12-131 postfix/smtp[939759]: cannot load Certification Authority data, CAfile="/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt", CApath="/etc/ssl/certs": disabling TLS support
Feb 22 13:51:47 ip-172-26-12-131 postfix/smtp[939759]: warning: TLS library problem: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69:fopen('/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt','r'):
Feb 22 13:51:47 ip-172-26-12-131 postfix/smtp[939759]: warning: TLS library problem: error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:76:
Feb 22 13:51:47 ip-172-26-12-131 postfix/smtp[939759]: warning: TLS library problem: error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib:../crypto/x509/by_file.c:199:
Feb 22 13:51:47 ip-172-26-12-131 postfix/smtp[939759]: 0A680BE63C: SASL authentication failed; server email-smtp.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com[35.183.211.80] said: 530 Must issue a STARTTLS command first
Feb 22 13:51:47 ip-172-26-12-131 postfix/smtp[939759]: 0A680BE63C: to=< mail@example.com>, relay=email-smtp.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com[99.79.137.249]:587, delay=20, delays=20/0.02/0.22/0, dsn=4.0.0, status=deferred (SASL authentication failed; server email-smtp.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com[99.79.137.249] said: 530 Must issue a STARTTLS command first)
Feb 22 13:51:49 ip-172-26-12-131 postfix/smtpd[936667]: warning: unknown[45.142.120.6]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Feb 22 13:51:49 ip-172-26-12-131 postfix/smtpd[936667]: disconnect from unknown[45.142.120.6] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=3/4
Feb 22 13:51:57 ip-172-26-12-131 postfix/postfix-script[939846]: warning: symlink leaves directory: /etc/postfix/./makedefs.out
Feb 22 13:51:57 ip-172-26-12-131 postfix/postfix-script[939973]: warning: /var/spool/postfix/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem and /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem differ
Feb 22 13:52:05 ip-172-26-12-131 postfix/smtpd[927078]: connect from unknown[45.142.120.180]
Feb 22 13:52:08 ip-172-26-12-131 postfix/smtpd[927078]: warning: unknown[45.142.120.180]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Feb 22 13:52:08 ip-172-26-12-131 postfix/smtpd[927078]: disconnect from unknown[45.142.120.180] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=3/4
Feb 22 13:52:12 ip-172-26-12-131 postfix/smtpd[936667]: connect from unknown[45.142.120.15]
Feb 22 13:52:12 ip-172-26-12-131 postfix/smtpd[924703]: connect from unknown[45.142.120.87]
Feb 22 13:52:18 ip-172-26-12-131 postfix/smtpd[924013]: connect from unknown[45.142.120.147]
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this message:

```
Feb 22 13:51:47 ip-172-26-12-131 postfix/smtp[939759]: warning: TLS library problem: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69:fopen('/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt','r'):
```

I suspect you're using Ubuntu server, the path to the `ca-bundle.crt` file should be `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`